# separating column the variations from the add to cart button woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, css, html

I'm using the "Worldmart" theme and I'm trying to separate the variations of the "Add to Cart" button. I'd like to have the variations displayed in column 1 and the "Add to Cart" button in column 2. Could someone please assist me with this? I've tried various approaches without success so far. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Exemple

[image]